# Scan AWS DynamoDB with ScanFilter with nested property

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I am trying to scan the dynamodb and my scan is working fine with root properties but is not working with nested properties. My code base is:

```
String workingProperty = "name"
String notWorkingProperty1 = "name.firstName"
String notWorkingProperty2 = "#name.firstName"
String notWorkingProperty3 = "#name.#firstName"

private Table table;
public List<Item> getAllFilteredItems() {

    ScanFilter scanFilter = new ScanFilter(propertyToLookFor).exists();
    StreamSupport.stream(table.scan(scanFilter).spliterator(), false)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

My JSON is:

```
{
  "name": {
    "firstName": "Manish"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scan Filters are legacy, you should try using a [Filter Expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.FilterExpression) instead with an [attribute_exists operator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html).

Try something like this (you may be able to remove the `withNameMap` and `withValueMap` but haven't tested)

```java
ScanSpec scanSpec = new ScanSpec().withFilterExpression("attribute_exists(name.firstName)").withNameMap(new NameMap()).withValueMap(new ValueMap());

results = table.scan(scanSpec)
```